# State of in-app purchases in ios

Tags: ios, swift3, in-app-purchase

I have a bunch of non-consumable and auto-renewable in-app purchases in my app. I want to know if the user has already purchased the app when I visit the in-app purchases. Is there a way to know this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement a solution for this problem by storing the purchases of a user and their purchase receipts  on your server.

So before showing products to a user, you can ask your server about which products user has purchased. And accordingly handle the interaction from there on.

P.S. :- Ideally you would not want to hide the already purchased products from a user as he might upgrade and then if he would want to downgrade back to same product then that won't be visible or vice versa.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is an ios provided function to know this information. For ex- in android you can make a request to know user's owned items. @Vikas Dadheech